# Multicolumn in longable not filling up to the left edge

Tags: memoir, longtable, multicolumn

I have the table that I have been successfully inputting into the document class article. In  that environment the note in this table was filling the whole space left to right. So the text on both left and right hand side were aligned to the edges. Now I am inserting this same table into the memoir. When inserted in memoir, the multicolumn notes are left justified and do not fill the space till the right edge. I have tried everything I could think of, but I can not fill the columns. I would appreciate help!

```
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{longtabu} {lllllll|llllll|llll|}
\caption{{Test Tests}}\label{table:tabBALANCE_NDM_sfe}\\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{No fe}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{School fe}\\  \hline 
& Baseline & Controls & Baseline & Controls\\  \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{No fe}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{School fe}\\  \hline 
& Baseline & Controls & Baseline & Controls\\  \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
\endfoot
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{11.0cm}}{Notes: Long long long long very long Long long long long very long Long long long long very long Longlong long long very long Long long long extremely long very longLonglong long long very long Long long long long very long Long longlong long very long Long longlong long very long Long long long long very long Long long long long very long  notes} \\ 
\endlastfoot
\textbf{Male }&\multicolumn{4}{c}{ }\\
FB&  0.010& -0.009&  0.019*&  0.005\\
&  0.014&  0.016&  0.010&  0.010 \\
\hline 
\hline 
\end{longtabu}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please help us help you: please post a full minimal example not just a sniplet like this. That makes it easy for others to copy your MWE and test it.

Comment: i can't confirm your claims: (i) using article document class the table is narrower than text width (ii) using `memoir` i obtain the same look-up and the same width of table as at `article` (iii) of-topic: you define 17 columns but use only 4,  etc. please clarify your question and provide small complete document,

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have found out that the problem was not the document type, but actually having {ragged2e} loaded.

Comment: Without ragged2e, things were fully justified both in the paragraphs of the text and in the multicolumn sections of the table. When {ragged2e} was added, even though the paragraphs in the text could be justified as desired by /justify, the text in multicolumn became unjustified, and nothing I did would justify it, even if the rest of the document was.  I solved the problem by removing rugged2e. Then to justify text following /centering, I had to write my own command to do so.